# how to make specific values not printed in java

Tags: java, selenium

i tried to get all product_id on category page, but somehow i values null printed on my console. i just want make exception that null values should not be printed. so my code is below

```
List<WebElement> myList=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='item product product-item col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-12 nopadding']//div"));
List<String> url=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){
    //loading text of each element in to array all_elements_text
    url.add(myList.get(i).getAttribute("data-sku"));
    //to print directly
    System.out.println(myList.get(i).getAttribute("data-sku"));
}
```

and the output like below

```
eF36FD35
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

only need null values not printed, thanks

Comment: Then add an **`if` statement**.

Comment: `if (v != null) System.out.println(v);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all the values without the **`NULL`** you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='item product product-item col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-12 nopadding']//div"));
List<String> url = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement myelem:myList)
{
    if(myelem.getAttribute("data-sku") != "null")
    url.add(myelem.getAttribute("data-sku"));
}
System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: This will cause a NPE when `myelem.getAttribute("data-sku")` is null.

Comment: @Henry Thanks. Updated my Answer